# Binary Tree -> Bool Function

Tags: function, types, ocaml

I want to make a function that traverses a binary tree, verifies some conditions and then returns a bool.

```
val valid : dtree -> bool

type dtree =
        Decision of string * int * dtree * string * int * dtree
      | Chance of string * int * dtree * string * int * dtree
      | Outcome of int
;;

let rec valid dt =
    match dt with
          Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, r) -> if choiceL=choiceR then false else valid l valid r
        | Chance(eventL, probL, l, eventR, probR, r) -> if  eventL=eventR && (probL + probR)<>100 then false else valid l valid r
        | Outcome value -> true 
;;
```

This gives me the following error:

```
 
Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, r) -> if choiceL=choiceR then false else valid l **valid** r
Error: This expression has type dtree -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
# Interrupted.
```

Comment: I do not get the same error message as you. You should copy and paste your code more carefully. Anyway, `valid l valid r` is clearly wrong. `valid l` is a boolean. You could logically-and it with another boolean such as `valid r`, the syntax would be `(valid r) && (valid l)`.

Comment: Thanks it solved it xD!, I'm still a begginer in this language x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I type your code in, I don't get the error you say.

By eye, this code looks wrong:

```
valid l valid r
```

I would expect something more like:

```
valid l && valid r
```